# Determine the radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

I was solving the Taylor's series in a vicinity of $z_{0}=1$ and the radius of convergence for the function $\frac {1} {(z^2 -2z +3)^2}$.

I found the Taylor's series: $= $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{n} 2^{-(n+2)} (n+1) (z-1)^{2n}}$

and then when i was finding the radius of convergence i used:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}=$$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {|(-1)^{n} 2^{-(n+2)} (n+1)|}{|(-1)^{n+1} 2^{-(n+3)} (n+2)|}=2$.

But in the solutions shows $R=\sqrt2$. Can someone explain me what i did wrong on the radius of convergence?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|}=\frac {1} {R}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor series is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n (z-1)^{n}\text{.}$$
Please note that the coefficient of $(z-1)^{2n}$ in
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{n} 2^{-(n+2)} (n+1) (z-1)^{2n}}$$ is $c_{2n}$ and that$c_{2n+1}=0$. So we have

$$c_n=\begin{cases}(-1)^{\frac n 2} 2^{-\frac{n} 2} \frac{n+2}{8}, &n\equiv 0\pmod 2 \\
0,& n\equiv1\pmod 2 \end{cases}$$

and therefore
$$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {c_{2n}}{c_{2n+2}}=R^2=2\text{.}$$

Answer (score 4):

You are taking the coefficient of $(z-1)^{n}$ as $(-1)^{n}2^{n+2}(n+1)$. You should take $a_{2n}=(-1)^{n}2^{n+2}(n+1)$ and $a_{2n-1}=0$.

Note that $\lim\sup |a_n^{1/n}|=\lim\sup |a_{2n}^{1/2n}|= 1/(\sqrt 2)$. Hence $R=\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! 
But could i solve this using the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {|a_{n}|}{|a_{n+1}|}={R}$?

Comment: Basically you get convergence for $|(z-1)|^{2} <2$ which means $|z-1| <\sqrt 2$. That is where you missed the square root.

Answer (score 0):

You could have made life simpler using $z=x+1$ to work around $x=0$. This would give
$$\frac {1} {(z^2 -2z +3)^2}=\frac{1}{\left(x^2+2\right)^2}$$ Now, let $x=\sqrt{2t}$ to make
$$\frac{1}{4 (t+1)^2}$$ from which the answer is quite simple.